# How to select scrollbar and change css?

Tags: html, css

I have this that is `width:100%;`. On bottom i have horizontal scrollbar. What i want is to scrollbar have `width: 60%` and `float:right;` .Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:scroll">
 content
</div>
```

So right now scrollbar is over all div and i want to have only half of it and to be on right side. I want to use only css, and not jquery because im using angular. So how can i do that?

Comment: please upload your mock-up image..

Comment: You want scrollbar to be not the same size as scrolling container? No way. This effect could only be simulated by creating additional element with scroll. All relations (scrolling pseudo scroll should trigger scrolling in original block) need JS. Also this will impact performance a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your scrollbar by setting the width of your div to 60%.

```css
.scroll{
  width:60%;
  overflow-x:scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
<p>
  content
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to have div 100% and scrollbar 60%;

Answer (score 0):

i don't think u can do that with pure `css` , u can inject jQuery easy if u r using bundle tool like `webpack2`

Answer (score 0):

I have used two `div` Just try this:-

```css
.scroll{
  width:60%;
  overflow-x:scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12" style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
<div class="scroll col-md-10">
<p>
  content
</p>
</div>
</div>
```